# Do I need more than one SSL certificate for my AWS EBS/EC2 application

Tags: ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb, amazon-route53, a-records

My application domain was bought on GoDaddy, the NS servers point to Route 53. Route53 has A records to Elastic Load Balancers for different urls which manage traffic to my Elastic Beanstalk.

Do I require more than one SSL certificate? Will a wildcard certificate be fine for this scenario (I assume it will be).
The reason I'm confused is because of the setup of the system and a lack of understanding how SSL certificates work with A records and Load Balancers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wildcard certificate should be sufficient, but you'll need to use CNAME records to map your subdomains to your various ELBs. A records are a recipe for disaster, because the ELBs change IP frequently.

You'll also need to load your certificate into AWS and create an HTTPS listener for each ELB, which is a lot of fun. [See the ELB developer's guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-https-load-balancers.html).

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little old, and I wanted to point out that today there is a free way to do this (rather than a wildcard cert which is typically expensive.)

Using Amazon certificate manager, you can request a cert for free, and assign a number of domains and subdomains to it. I have a cert running that has a total of six subdomains across two different domains. Four of the subdomains all point to the same application, with the load balancer on elastic beanstalk application pointing to the one cert.